# pasar una variable de un archivo php a otro

Tags: php

necesito pasar mi variable $_proceso de mi documento guardar.php a datos.php por URL

tengo lo siguiente en guardar.php

```html
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$_Proceso = $_POST["Proceso"];
$_Actividades = $_POST["Actividad"];
$_Entrada = $_POST["Entrada"];
$_Salida = $_POST["Salida"];
$query = "INSERT INTO proceso (Nombre_proceso,actividades,entrada, salida)
VALUES ('$_Proceso', '$_Actividades', '$_Entrada', '$_Salida'); ";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) die($conn->error);
header("Location: ../form_validation.php?$_Proceso=$_Proceso");
exit;
?>
```

y tengo esto es mi archivo datos.php

```html
<?php
require_once 'PHP/login.php';
 
              $_proceso = $_GET['$_Proceso'];
              $_query = "SELECT id,Nombre_proceso FROM proceso WHERE Nombre_proceso = '$_proceso'";
                $_result = $conn->query($_query);
                if (!$_result) die($conn->error);
 
                while ($_row = mysqli_fetch_array($_result)){
                    $_proceso = $_row["Nombre_proceso"];
                    $_id = $_row["id"];
                        }
              ?>
```

pero me da el siguiente error "Notice: Undefined variable: _Proceso"

Comment: en guardar.php tienes `$_POST` y en datos.php tienes `$_GET`

Comment: tienes diferentes Verbos HTTP, en la primera es POST y la ultima no prueba dejando ambos con el mismo que sea GET

Comment: creo no estoy seguro, pero al pasar las variables no deberían llevar signo de pesos al momento de pasarla por la URL

Comment: ya puse los dos por $_GET y me sigue marcando el mismo error :/ , el guardar.php lo tengo por $_POST por que recibo la inficion de un formulario con <form method="POST">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error radica en el nombre de la variable. 
Previamente has declarado $_Proceso y al hacer header("$_Proceso=$_Proceso") se reemplaza por el valor de la variable declarada.
Quedaría como header("Valor=Valor").

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente como dice Lucasato se soluciona cambiando la línea

```
header("Location: ../form_validation.php?$_Proceso=$_Proceso");
```

Por

```
header(‘Location: ../form_validation.php?$_Proceso=‘.$_Proceso);
```

Si dentro de unas comillas dobles hay una variable, al ejecutarse se cambia por el valor, con lo que como bien dice lucasato el resultado es valor=valor

Answer (score 0):

Como dice lucasato, hay algo que no me cuadra con tu POST.
en tu archivo guardar.php reemplaza

```
header("Location: ../form_validation.php?$_Proceso=$_Proceso");
```

por

```
header("Location: ../form_validation.php?proceso=" . $_POST['Proceso']);
```

En tu archivo datos.php recojes así tu variable

```
$proceso = $_POST['proceso'];
```

Si no te funciona puedes hecharle un vistazo a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)